# How to change input field using javascript onclick?

Tags: javascript, onclick

Is it possible to change input field using javascript onclick??
My code:

```
<form>
 <input type="text" id="demo" value="John">
</form>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me!</button>  
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").value = "Hello World";
  }
</script>
```

it is successful to change the text, but it is failed to change input field value
anyidea how to solve it??? Thank you very much[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update the `value` field of the HTML as well, use [`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

```html
<form>
 <input type="text" id="demo" value="John">
</form>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me!</button>  
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").setAttribute("value", "Hello World");
  }
</script>
```